# Android: Multiple dex files define (two libraries have same classes)

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

There are two third-party libraries as following:

[lib1.jar]　　　　　[lib2.jar] 
　a/A.class　　　　 c/C.class 
　b/B.class　　　　 b/B.class

I'm using Android Studio, and when I put both of them in the app/libs folder I got the below error:

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lb/B;
```

I cannot modify the content of the jar files, so is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to modify the jar somehow. You could delete the duplicate class from one of the jars, or use something like jarjar to change the package name of the classes in one of the jars.